# Unsetting session in if statement. If statement ignored

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a wierd problem with $_SESSION in woprdpress namely I would like to clear session variables on all pages except single pages of custom  post type - product.

I use the condition:

```
if(!is_singular('product')) {
    unset($_SESSION);
}
```

The problem is the session is cleared on all pages including the product single pages. The if statement is simply ignored. I tried placing it in template_redirect hook or just in header.php file and it didn't matter.

I start the session using action hook:

```
function register_my_session() {
    if( !session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'register_my_session', 9);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Raf

Comment: "*I would like to clear session variables on all pages except single pages*", you do realize session variables are shared across all pages for the session user? And.. `unset($_SESSION)` whipes all data.

Comment: Yes, I mean I want to filre the unset_session() when user's on all pages except product single pages.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I mean I want to filre the unset_session() when user's on all
>   pages except product single pages

Why not turn it around and fire on all pages except for product pages then?

```
if (!is_product())
    unset($_SESSION);
```

To filter out admin:

```
if (!is_product() && !current_user_can('manage_options'))
    unset($_SESSION);
```

Only on single pages and not product and not admin:

```
if (is_single() && !is_product() && !current_user_can('manage_options'))
    unset($_SESSION);
```